# Marker is not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

When I tried to add a marker like this it is not showing

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(transitLatLong).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin))
```

but it is showing when I tried like one below without assigning to a Marker Object

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(transitLatLong).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin))
```

Comment: try to call `mMap.clear()` then add marker.

Comment: there are two other markers inside the map. will this affect them

Comment: yes, It will remove all marker. You can also add them after calling this.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal I tried it. but still not showing

Comment: Both lines are equivalent. Assigning the marker reference won't make a difference. There should be an issue somewhere else in your code.